# Should I add multiple migration files into git repository with Django?

Tags: django, git, django-models

With Django whenever I make a change in the models, another migration file is generated automatically after I run following :

```
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

What is the best way to keep these migration files for development, should they be committed to the source control ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It should be versioned. It guarantee the traceability of database changes.

Comment: Is this applicable both from development and production environment perspective ? Imagine, only having a development perspective, your models change rapidly. Do you really need to keep trace of that ?

Comment: Its a good practice.If you made a mistake under developement and dont have production instance, you could delete the database and recreate it to ignore migrations. Django uses a hidden table to manage the migrations, so you need them.